# Google Cloud SQL

Tags: mysql, windows, google-cloud-sql

I am getting this error ***"ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0"*** whenever I try to connect from my windows command prompt to the cloud sql instance database with the "mysql -host instance-ip -u username -p password ... and my OS is Windows 7

Comment: Could you provide us more details? Have you authorized [your public IP](http://whatismyipaddress.com/)? Did you set a root password?
To discard an issue with the authorized IPs you can allow all of them (0.0.0.0/0) and once you get access you can restrict it to some specific IPs and ranges.

Comment: No i haven't authorized anything.. and that is why am requesting for help because I don't know how to authorize an IP

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you have allowed your ip to access your cloud sql instance ([doc](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/access-control#appaccess))

Comment: Thanks...I didn't authorise my public ip address on the google cloud sql instance authorized network.... I authorised the wrong the ip address....